# Pandas mul and mean without loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

**How to do this without the loop?**

```
C = pd.DataFrame(index=B.columns,columns=A.columns).fillna(0)

for idx,item in B.iteritems():
    C.loc[idx] = movies_profile.mul(item,axis=0).mean()
```

For example:
*A.shape is 100 rows × 18 columns*
*B.shape is 100 rows × 20 columns*

Then:
*C.shape is 20 rows × 18 columns*

Comment: kindly share sample data with expected output

Answer (score 0):

It looks like matrix multiplication:

```
B.T.dot(A) / A.shape[0]
```